# A periodic table planet

Tags: planets, chemistry

## Background

There was this bored god that had nothing to do, and was tired of looking after earth due to all of the stupid wars that the humans got themselves in, so he got something that humans had abstractly made themselves, and decided to punish them, to make them reflect on how foolish they were and the amount of damage they could cause with their current technology.

### World-building

Let's take the periodic table, curve it into a sphere, (so each of the 118 elements cover the same volume) and make a planet out of it (size of earth), with the material being the element (longest living isotope) that occupies that space itself, and covers the planet with a metre of soil and then vegetation. He puts the planet at the L3 Langrage point, where he gets all the humans' position on the planet, copies it, and puts it on the new planet (Call this Nemesis). Now he seals both planets with a sphere made out of completely transparent but unbreakable material, a few thousand kilometres away from the surface. I wanted to compare the population of Earth and Nemesis after a century, to compare the population count, but wanted to be inspired.

Going back to the moment the humans were placed, what would happen in one second? One day? One year?

Comment: In equal amounts?? Of each and every isotope??? What makes you think it would last a second? Also, which periodic table? Are you including synthesized elements? Speculated ones on the island of stability? How is this about worldbuilding? It's more like "how quickly and spectacularly can I blow-up a planet?".

Comment: This sounds more like a "write my story for me"

Comment: he worte 118 - that includes synthetic ones and nuclear explosive oines

Comment: your bored god is basically a teenager who likes messing with pyrotechnics.

Comment: Everybody dies because there is no air. Even if you supply the air, everybody dies because there is no water. Even if you supply the water, everybody dies because there is no food. (And you may want to rethink the specifications to include the state of the elements in the initial volume. For example, are hydrogen and oxygen packed as gases or what?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Randal Munroe did a very similar thought experiment. Probably the planet wouldn't survive the first seconds.
https://englishatlc.files.wordpress.com/2016/03/randall-munroe-periodic-wall-of-elements.pdf

EDIT: to quote the reference

"Unfortunately for our project, the transuranic elements don't vanish quietly. They decay radioactively. And most of them decay into things that also decay. A cube of any of the highest-numbered elements would decay within seconds, releasing a tremendous amount of energy.
The result wouldn't be like a nuclear  explosion-it would be a nuclear explosion. However, unlike a fission bomb, it wouldn't be a chain reaction-just a reaction. It would all happen at once.

The flood of energy would instantly turn you-and the rest of the periodic table-to plasma. The blast would be similar to that of a medium-sized nuclear detonation, but the radioactive fallout would be much, much worse-a veritable
salad of everything on the periodic table turning into everything else as fast as possible.
A mushroom cloud would rise over the city. The top of the plume would reach up through the stratosphere, buoyed by its own heat. If you were in a populated area, the immediate casualties from the blast would be staggering, but the long­ term contamination from the fallout would be even worse.
The fallout wouldn't be normal, everyday  radioactive fa llout 9- it would be like a nuclear bomb that kept exploding. The debris would spread around the world, releasing thousands of times more radioactivity than the Chernobyl disaster. Entire regions would be devastated; the cleanup would stretch on for centuries.
While collecting things is certainly fun, when it comes to chemical elements, you do not want to collect them all."

Comment: The question did get inspired by Randall Munroe, yes.

Answer (score 4):

A whole planet, evenly divided into pure elemental segments.

If you include *all* elements, there are several that will explode, with cosmic-shattering violence, in the first one second. From simple radioactive decay heating. (some in the first nanosecond, actually)

So let's ban all radioactive elements.
.
oops.
Now your planet does not exist at all, because ***all*** elements are radioactive, at *some* timescale. Even hydrogen will eventually decay, on the order of 10^34 years.

Ok, so let's ban exactly those elements that cause more than 100K of heating in that one second, so we eliminate explosive effects.

The boundaries between the various elements will be very few and far between, and at planetary scale mere chemical reaction between adjacent zones can be ignored at the 1-second timescale.

What temperature does your planet start out at?
Those segments that are gases, will expand outwards at a rate commensurate with their pressure (which is INconveniently also not specified)
Those that are liquid will flow under gravity, which depend on the size and mass of the planet (which is also INconveniently not specified)
Those that are solid will fall down into the voids below them, if there are any (this depends on the layout/arrangement of the elemental sectors, which is, yes, INconveniently not specified), or will crumble into adjacent voids, or will slump down under gravity.

The more one looks at the question, the more **essential** descriptive specifications are noted that are absolutely required to be able to answer the question, but are currently absent!

Comment: Proton decay isn't verified yet.